# Can I cross-sign x509 certificates using Python cryptography?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, x509, python-cryptography

Pretty much what the question says.  The docs have an example for generating a certificate signing request and loading the certificate a CA sends you back, but nothing more complex like having a certificate cross-signed by another CA.  Is it possible?

Comment: Cross signed certificates are little else than the same public key (in a CSR) signed by different CA certificates. Technically, there is no difference.

Comment: I see.  I was thinking X509 supported multiple signatures on a certificate but I see this is not so.  Thanks.  It seems I'm looking for something more like OpenPGP.

Comment: Possibly, I am not aware of your use case. If you are looking for info on this kind of topics I'd recommend going through [security.se], maybe ask some initial questions in their chat.